# Resource identifier using id and textual description in URL...why not just id?

Tags: url, rest

Many websites use the following convention for identifying REST-based resources...

```
gizmodo.com/453387/new-mobile-app-for-traveling-time
```

If the `id` portion of the url, `453387`, uniquely identifies the resource, what's the point of adding `new-mobile-app-for-traveling-time` at the end of the URL?

Comment: It's actually the same as in SO!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess they use such URL for SEO reasons.

Comment: I've never done SEO, so I've never looked at it that way, but that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

Also to make the url more human readable.